# C++ Difference between inline anonymous instances and named instances

Tags: c++

In a logging context, I would like to use a temporary instance of a utility class to collect some output, and use the destructor to dispose of the collected output. For example, printing to standard output as below.

I am noticing behavior differences depending whether the utility instance is constructed as an inline, anonymous instance as compared with a named automatic instance.

The named instances result in expected behavior and output.  The inline instances have difficulty with the first insertion operation, apparently only working on operands which have simple conversions to int.

What is the difference between instances used in these different ways?

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class Util
{
public:
    std::ostringstream m_os;

    Util() {}
    ~Util() { std::cout << m_os.str() << std::endl;}
};



int main (void)
{
// ----------- Using temporary anonymous instance - 
    //  Output does not match expected, and the first insertion seems to
    //  only be able to handle instances that can be converted to int.

    // Following prints "97key=val", but expect "akey=val"
    (Util()).m_os << char('a') << std::string("key") << "=" << std::string("val");

    // Following prints "0x80491eakey=val", but expect "Plain old C string key=val"
    (Util()).m_os << "Plain old C string " << std::string("key") << "=" << std::string("val");

    // Following results in syntax error
    // error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘Util().Util::m_os <<
    (Util()).m_os << std::string("key") << "=" << std::string("val");


// ----------- Using named instance - output matches expected

    // Block results in print "akey=val"
    {
        Util inst;
        inst.m_os  << char('a') << std::string("key") << "=" << std::string("val");
    }

    // Block results in print "Plain old C string key=val"
    {
        Util inst;
        inst.m_os  << "Plain old C string " << std::string("key") << "=" << std::string("val");
    }

    // Block results in print "key=val"
    {
        Util inst;
        inst.m_os  << std::string("key") << "=" << std::string("val");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They should be the same. http://ideone.com/IveuCx What compiler are you using?

Comment: Also:$ c++ --version
c++ (SUSE Linux) 4.4.1 [gcc-4_4-branch revision 150839]
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: The latest version of GCC is 4.8.1. Can't you update your compiler? GCC 4.4.1 is 4 years old.

Comment: @Simple It works for you because ideone is compiling in C++11 mode. Even in GCC 4.8, it will (and is supposed to) fail if you're not using C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(Util())` creates a temporary object. As a result, `(Util()).m_os` is also a temporary object.

There are some definitions of `operator<<` as a member function, and some other definitions of it as a freestanding function. The former work on temporary objects, the latter does not, because a temporary cannot be bound to a reference-to-stream. Simplifying your code to a full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct stream
{
    stream& operator<<(int)
    { puts("operator<<(int)"); return *this; }
};

stream& operator<<(stream& s, char)
{ puts("operator<<(char)"); return s; }

struct streamwrapper
{
    stream s;
};

int main()
{
    streamwrapper w;
    w.s << 'a'; // outputs operator<<(char)

    streamwrapper().s << 'a'; // outputs operator<<(int)
}
```

Since the overloads you expected are unavailable, yet others are not, those other overloads get used instead of giving you a hard compiler error.